# is using delimited parameter in stored procedure dangerous?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My C# side is like :

```
if(Request.QueryString["ValuesFromUser"]!=null)
{
    ValuesFromUser_ = Request["ValuesFromUser"];
}

DataTable dtle = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sqda;
sqda = new SqlDataAdapter("Checkforuserinput", Connection);
SqlParameter SQP = sqda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@arg", SqlDbType.VarChar);
SQP.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
SQP.Value = "ValuesFromUser_";
sqda.Fill(dtle );
```

User will pass few arguments like `"user1,user2,user3"`

In my sql side :

```
Create PROC [dbo].[Checkforuserinput] @arg VARCHAR(50)= 'All'
As
    Select * 
    from UserData 
    where User in (SELECT * 
                   FROM SplitDelimiterString(@Arg, ','))
```

And SplitDelimiterString Function is like :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitDelimiterString] (@StringWithDelimiter VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter VARCHAR(8))

RETURNS @ItemTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(8000))

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartingPosition INT;
    DECLARE @ItemInString VARCHAR(8000);

    SELECT @StartingPosition = 1;
    --Return if string is null or empty
    IF LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) = 0 OR @StringWithDelimiter IS NULL RETURN; 

    WHILE @StartingPosition > 0
    BEGIN
        --Get starting index of delimiter .. If string
        --doesn't contain any delimiter than it will returl 0 
        SET @StartingPosition = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@StringWithDelimiter); 

        --Get item from string        
        IF @StartingPosition > 0                
            SET @ItemInString = SUBSTRING(@StringWithDelimiter,0,@StartingPosition)
        ELSE
            SET @ItemInString = @StringWithDelimiter;
        --If item isn't empty than add to return table    
        IF( LEN(@ItemInString) > 0)
            INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) VALUES (@ItemInString);            

        --Remove inserted item from string
        SET @StringWithDelimiter = SUBSTRING(@StringWithDelimiter,@StartingPosition + 
                     LEN(@Delimiter),LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) - @StartingPosition)

        --Break loop if string is empty
        IF LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) = 0 BREAK;
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Is this code safe or in risk for SQL injection?

Or should i use this :

```
Create PROC [dbo].[Checkforuserinput] @arg VARCHAR(50)= 'All'
As
    declare @query nvarchar(max)
    set @query = 'Select * from UserData where User in ('+@Arg+')'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: The split function is definitely better. At worst, it should throw an exception in your C# command call. The second one is ripe for SQL injection. Also, note that you can inner join the result of that function, rather than using a subquery, if that's appropriate for you (it will be much faster, but it might get you multiple rows if that's possible given your data).

Comment: to expand on what @Luaan was saying in regards to the second one, there's nothing preventing someone from passing something like `user1, 'drop table UserData` (or something to that effect anyways) into the query.  Your split function looks fine from a quick glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any forseeable problems with the split function, but passing a table valued parameter would be more efficient.

SQL

```
CREATE TYPE ArrayOfString AS TABLE
(
    Item VARCHAR(50)
);
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[Checkforuserinput] @arg ArrayOfString READONLY
    AS
        SELECT * 
        FROM UserData 
        WHERE User IN (SELECT Item FROM @arg)
GO
```

C#

Write a helper function to write any `IEnumerable(string)` into a `DataTable` that the SQL Server will understand.

```
public static class SqlExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToSqlArray(this IEnumerable<string> collection)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable("ArrayOfString");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item", typeof(string)));

        foreach(var item in collection)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = item;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(Request.QueryString["ValuesFromUser"]!=null)
{
    ValuesFromUser_ = Request["ValuesFromUser"];
}

var values = ValuesFromUser_.Split(",");

using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Checkforuserinput", Connection))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arg", values.ToSqlArray());
    adapter.Fill(dtle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of SQL Server, you may want to consider passing a table-valued parameter to your stored procedure.

Table-valued parameters provide an easy way to marshal multiple rows of data from a client application to SQL Server without requiring multiple round trips or special server-side logic for processing the data. You can use table-valued parameters to encapsulate rows of data in a client application and send the data to the server in a single parameterized command. The SqlParameter is populated by using the AddWithValue method and the SqlDbType is set to Structured.

The following link provides a good overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx